# Cant access the site after I made a clone of Magento 2.3.5-p1 Instance using AMI on EC2

Tags: magento2, aws

I would be really grateful if you can give me a solution to this.

1. My main website is working fine on a custom domain "www.example.com". I made a clone of this using AMI and created a new instance on AWS.
2. Now on the new instance(cloned) I cannot access the website I tried changing the base url to IP of the new instance and also to the localhost:8080. None of them appear to be working.
3. I did run cache:flush and access rights to various directory (html,var,app,etc,pub,generated) non seems to be working

Please help, your input will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it is fixed.

1. Flush:Cache
2. Setup:upgrade
3. indexer:reindex
4. Access rights

And starts working again.